# TypeScript - How to compute wrapper objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

On console,

```
> a = new Number(1)
Number {1}
> b = new Number(2)
Number {2}
> a + b
3
```

Using Type Script,

```
let a: Number = new Number(1);
let b: Number = new Number(2);
a + b;
```

gives error:

```
> tsc file.ts
file.ts(3,1): error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Number' and 'Number'.
```

---

How to compute wrapper objects of primitive types `number`/`string`/`boolean`?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2031

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.valueOf()` to get the number:

```
let a: Number = new Number(1);
let b: Number = new Number(2);
a.valueOf() + b.valueOf();
```

or use `as number`:

```
(a as number) + (b as number)
```

Comment: All primitive types, including `string` are immutable. Is wrapper type(say `String`) object mutable?

Comment: The wrapper is mutable just like any other object (you can add new properties to the object).  However, you can't change the already existing properties of it.

Comment: Notice that if a is not a Number but any compatible type (any), type safety will be lost. `(a as number) + (b as number)` could be a string but TS considers it a number. I'd say that `+a + +b` is more clunky but safe way.